# An angular component does not remain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have a component for menu:

```
    <nav class="mxmls-mobile-nav"> 
  <button class="mobile-menu-btn visible-xs visible-sm " ng-click="asideVm.open = false">
    <i class="ion-android-close"></i>
  </button>
</nav>
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs visible-sm " ui-sref="layout.dashboard">
 <img src="assets/images/logo/mxmls-logo.png" alt="" height="30" >
</a>
<nav class="mxmls-main-menu">
  <ul class="mxmls-menu">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" class="{{item.extraClass}}" ng-repeat="item in asideVm.menuItems" ng-click="asideVm.activateSubmenuParent(item)" ng-class="{'close-menu':item.submenu, 'active': item.activateSubmenu || item.active}">
      <a ui-sref="{{item.ui_state}}" ng-if="item.ui_state" ng-click="asideVm.changeType(); asideVm.removeSubmenuActiveState();" ng-bind-html="item.name">
        <!-- <i class="fa {{item.icon}} pull-left"></i> -->
        <!-- <span class="selected"></span> -->
      </a>
      <a ui-sref-active="active" ng-if="!item.ui_state;" ng-click="item.submenu = !item.submenu;asideVm.saveStatusMenu()">
        <!-- <i class="fa {{item.icon}} pull-left"></i> -->{{item.name}}
        <span class="icon-arrow pull-right"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="mxmls-submenu" ng-if="item.sections" ng-class="{'hide':item.submenu}">
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-repeat="subItem in item.sections" ng-class="{'active': subItem.active}">
          <a ui-sref="{{subItem.ui_state}}" ng-click="asideVm.changeType(); asideVm.activateSubmenuParent(subItem);">
           <!-- <i class="fa {{item.icon}} pull-left"></i> -->{{subItem.name}}
           <!-- <span class="selected"></span> -->
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

The elements in asideVm.menuItems have the attrib "active" for focus it when clic on that, using the class "active" (Here all ok).
But, when click on a link like:

```
<a href="/acm/venta/search" class="btn btn-base ng-binding" ui-sref="layout.acm.state.search({type:'venta'})">Iniciar análisis</a>
```

the class "active" lose in the menu. I need help :/

The array "asideVm.menuItems" is stored in the cookie (And the attrib "active" too) and i get it when the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer XD

first, initialice an variable for flag if is initializing:

```
vm.initialize = true;
```

after: check, with "scope.watch", if the "url/location" is changed; if that and is not initializing, use the function "$state.reload()" for refresh the component/directive/control:

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){
    return $location.path();
      }, function(value){
        if(!vm.initialize)
        {
          console.log(value);
          $state.reload();
        }
        else
        {
          vm.initialize=false;
        }
      });
```